# How do you set an integer in CFPreferencesSetAppValue?

Tags: objective-c

I have some problem to write an integer value to the preferences using this:

```
CFPreferencesSetAppValue(CFSTR("theKey"), CFSTR("0"),(CFStringRef)theID);
```

The code above will write into preferences as string, how to instead write it as an integer (and so does boolean)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For booleans, you use `CFBoolean` (the two values of which are `kCFBooleanTrue` and `kCFBooleanFalse`). For other numbers, you use `CFNumber`.

Since your question is tagged for Objective-C, you can use `(CFTypeRef)@YES`, `(CFTypeRef)@NO`, and/or `(CFTypeRef)@(<expr>)` to create the objects.

And, of course, if you're setting preferences for the current app, using `NSUserDefaults` is more natural.